# How do you format React Component props alphabetically on save?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, format, eslint, prettier

How does one format props and typescript definitions alphabetically on save? Ideally it is some configuration for the whole project as opposed to a VSCode plugin (though I'm open a plugin too at this point).

```js
// the items inside ButtonProps should be sorted alphabetically
type ButtonProps = {
    name: string;
    id: string;
    onPress: () => void;
    disabled: boolean;
}

const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
    // this should also be sorted alphabetically
    const {name, id, onPress, disabled} = props;

    return <>My Prop</>
}
```

I tried [react/sort-prop-types](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/sort-prop-types.md) and [sort-keys](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/sort-keys) but I really don't know what I'm doing with eslint. It still doesn't format alphabetically on save. My eslint config is below:

```js
// .eslintrc.json
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    "react/sort-prop-types": [
      2,
        {
            "callbacksLast": true,
            "shorthandFirst": true,
            "ignoreCase": false,
            "noSortAlphabetically": false,
            "reservedFirst": true
        }
    ],
    "sort-keys": ["error", "asc", {"caseSensitive": true, "natural": false, "minKeys": 2}], 
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a VSCode extension called `Sort lines`. It doesn't do it on save though but all you have to do is highlight your props, press `cmd` + `shift` + `p` for Mac or `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` for Windows to open the Command Palette and select `Sort lines`.

Comment: Can you show me how I can configure my VSCode to sorting propTypes in Nextjs on Save file?

Answer (score 1):

I tried `eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix` in vscode with proper settings mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix

I did not use `sort-keys` but just `eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix`